# I can't boot into Recovery mode

Tags: macos, recovery

Running macOS 11.7.2
Recovery partition is present as disk1s4 632.2 MB

I can't boot into the recovery partition.
cmd-r gives me internet recovery.

Many thanks if any one could advise me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of messing with your recovery partition. If it only boots into internet recovery mode it means that the partition is either corrupted or was broken.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well JOOT49, this is not an answer to my issue nor is it a solution. You assume too much, not nice. The solution, I found out, is to press cmd+shift+R whilst restarting the machine.